# In R Is it possible to do matrix operations on matrices that contain functions?

Tags: r, matrix, package

I am working with a mathematical model where functions are contained within matrices to simulate the dynamics of biological populations.  This normally requires calling the function to update the matrix, then carrying out matrix multiplication to project the dynamics of the system into the next time step.  I'm wondering if its possible to embed a function directly within a matrix and to skip explicitly updating the matrix elements.

The model looks like this:
The state of the system is in matrix X1, eg

```
X <- c(0,10)
```

The system changes according to matrix A

```
A <- matrix(data = c(0, NA,0.75,0.75),nrow =2,byrow = T)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.00   NA
[2,] 0.75 0.75
```

Where the element NA is a function of element 2 in X1, like this

```
f.A.12 <- function(X.2){1 + (1 - X.2/1000)}
```

So the system is simulated like this:
Update marix A based on status of X

```
A[1,2] <- f.A.12(X[2])
```

Iterate model with updated matrix:

```
A%*%X

     [,1]
[1,] 19.9
[2,]  7.5
```

This then gets iterated 1000 times, updating A before each multiplication

The real model uses much larger matrices containing multiple functions.
Is there an R package that allows me to embed the functions directly within the matrix, such as

```
A.with.fx <- matrix(data = c(0,    f.A.12,
                             0.75, 0.75),   nrow =2,byrow = T)
```

And then to carry out regular matrix operations, eg

```
A.with.fx%*%X
```

Without having to explicitly assign the values in A that are a function of X in each iteration?
I guess this would require a function that is a modified `%*%` operation that does the necessary lookup on its own.

Comment: All elements in the matrix must be the same type. This means that you can have a matrix of functions, but you cannot embed a function in a matrix of type numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be trying to break your problem down in a way that ends up not very clean or standard. Instead of thinking about matrices that contain scalar functions, think about a function that returns a matrix.

You can trivially do:

```
update <- function(X) matrix(c(0,.75, f.A.12(X[2]), .75), 2)
```

and with some abuse of notation:

```
`%**%` <- function(f, X) f(X) %*% X
X <- update %**% X
```

Note that `%*%` is an S4 generic, so it's a bit of a pain to overload it.

Alternatively, with a little algebra you can split `A` into a constant and function of `X`, and handle the complexity that way:

```
A = [ [  0, 2 - x[2]/1000],
      [.75, .75]            ]
  = [[0, 2],[.75, .75]] + [[0, - x[2]/1000],[0, 0 ] ]
  = c + g(x)
```

so the update can be rewritten:

```
X = c * X + g(X) * X
```

where  `g` is the matrix-valued function, yielding a slower but cleaner:

```
g <- function(X) matrix( c(0,0, -x[2]/1000), 0), 2,2)
C <- matrix(c(0,.75,2,.75),2)
X <- c(0,10)

> (X <- C %*% X + g(X) %*% X)  
     [,1]  
[1,] 19.9  
[2,]  7.5
```

We can do a little better by composing `g(X) %*% X` into one function :

```
f <- function(x)  c( -x[2]^2 / 1000, 0   )
```

giving:

```
> X <- c(0,10)
> (X <- C %*% X + f(X) )
     [,1]
[1,] 19.9
[2,]  7.5
```

Here's a couple benchmarks:

```
microbenchmark(two_step={A <- update(X); A %*% X},
                  split=(C %*% X + g(X) %*% X), 
               composed= C %*% X + f(X)  )
Unit: microseconds
     expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
 two_step 3.608 4.0900 4.85369 4.3730 4.9290 13.089   100
    split 5.587 6.0400 7.72511 6.4900 7.3785 53.047   100
 composed 2.266 2.4835 2.78195 2.6815 2.9745  6.697   100
```